How to use the load function in Sveltekit with TypeScript?
I'm currently learning Sveltekit following the official tutorial. I got stuck on this page of the tutorial when I tried to mix in some TypeScript with the load function.
When I use the arrow function, everything checks perfectly:
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types'
import { posts } from './data'

export const load: PageServerLoad = () => {
    return {
            summaries: posts.map(post => ({
            slug: post.slug,
            title: post.title,
        }))
    }
}

But when I use a regular function, I get this error 'summaries' does not exist in type 'PageLoad':
import type { PageServerLoad } from './$types'
import { posts } from './data'

export function load(): PageServerLoad  {
    return {
        summaries: posts.map(post => ({
            slug: post.slug,
            title: post.title,
        }))
    }
}

I thought these two functions were equivalent. Did I miss something?

The definitions are not equivalent, your arrow function is a PageServerLoad but your vanilla function returns a PageServerLoad. (In other words in the first example you specify the type of load, in the second you specify the return type of it.)

@jonrsharpe: That should be an answer.

Thanks jonrsharpe for the clarification you've been a big help

Thanks to @jonrsharpe comment now I understand the difference between the two functions: the arrow function is of type PageServerLoad but the vanilla function returns a PageServerLoad.
